# Webscraping - Extracting individual items from a column that contains multiple items (Nokogiri, Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, web-development-server

I'm new to web development and trying to learn webscraping. The column that I'm attempting to extract from contains multiple items and I want to get the individual items separately.

```
site = "http://www.cyrptomarketcap.com"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(site))
coin_table = doc.css("table").sort { |x,y| y.css("tr").count <=> x.css("tr").count }.first
rows = coin_table.cc("tr")
rows = rows.select { |row| row.css("th").empty? }
data = rows.map do |row|
  [row.at_css("td:nth-child(2)").try(:text)]
end
```

The result of this is:

=> [["\n \n \n \n BTC\n Bitcoin\n "], ["\n \n \n \n XRP\n Ripple\n "], ... ]

What do I need to do to get just the names?

Comment: What do you mean by "just the names"?

Comment: [Bitcoin, Ripple, ... ]

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the following to your `data` variable:

```
data.flatten.map { |s| s.split("\n")[-2].gsub(' ', '') }
```

It gives result:

```
["Bitcoin", "Ripple", ...]
```